# Handling a hash as a function argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, methods

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to handle a hash as a function argument.

For example, if I state a function this way:

```
def function_name(options = {})
  ...
end
```

I would like to pass to the `function_name` a hash like

```
{"key1"=>"value_1", "key2"=>"value2", "..." => "..."}
```

and then use that inside the function.

**What is the *best\common* (Rails) way to do that?**

P.S.: I have seen the `extract_option!` method somewhere, but I don't know where I can find some documentation and whether I need that in order to accomplish what I aim.

Comment: I think you mean this: http://apidock.com/rails/Array/extract_options%21. But your example does not take advantage of it unless your signature is "def function_name(*args)". Passing a hash as options is completely standard and you have to do nothing special, as Jakub says.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply use the definition you provided:

```
def function_name(options = {})
  puts options["key1"]
end
```

Call it with:

```
function_name "key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2"
```

or

```
function_name({"key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2"})
```

[Array#extract_options!](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/extract_options!) is simply used with methods that have variable method arguments like this:

```
def function_name(*args)
  puts args.inspect
  options = args.extract_options!
  puts options["key1"]
  puts args.inspect
end

function_name "example", "second argument", "key1" => "value"
# prints
["example", "second argument", { "key1" => "value" }]
value
["example", "second argument"]
```

Another useful method is [Hash#symbolize_keys!](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/symbolize_keys!) which lets you not care about whether you pass in strings or symbols to your function so that you can always access things like this `options[:key1]`.

Answer (score 3):

The way you have it declared in your example will work fine.

```
def function(options = {})
    item = options[:item]
    need_milk = options[:milk] || false
    cow = options[:bovine]
end

function(:item => "Something")
```

In the case above, `item == "Something"`, `need_milk == false` and `cow == nil`.

`extract_options` is simply an addition to the Array and `Hash` class via Rails.

```
def function(something, else, *args)
   options = args.extract_options! # returns Hash
end
```

It is useful if you plan on having many different types of parameters in `args` but if you only want `Hash` options, your original way is fine.

Here's a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/871679) of the code in Rails for `extract_options!` I personally use it in my code at work by just writing it to an external file and requiring it into my project.

Comment: This is my favourite way to do it. +1 for the `|| false`, can stop the method blowing up if a user forgets something :)

Answer (score -4):

Ruby makes this easy, and you were already doing it right.

Here is a poetry-mode (minimal, DSL-style) example:

```
 def f x = {}
   p x
 end

 f :a => :b
 {:a=>:b}

 f
 {}

 f :a => :b, :c => :d
 {:a=>:b, :c=>:d}
```